# How useful are profile backlinks for SEO?

Tags: seo, backlinks, technical-seo, domain-authority

My own website is a tech blog. I want to increase the backlink profile and domain authority of my blog. In some of the articles I read, the importance of the profile backlink was mentioned. If I subscribe to a site that has nothing to do with my website and put a link to my own site in my profile on that site, will it be beneficial for SEO? For example, a flower seller signs up on Stack Overflow to get a backlink and puts the website link on their profile. Will this be helpful for SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of profile backlinks are `nofollow` links (and if they aren't they probably should be) so don't carry any direct SEO benefit, except that it allows *users* to find you, so could potentially drive traffic if your profile is popular (and relevant).

Profile links are user-submitted content, so it's in the interests of the source website to make it *nofollow* in order to curb spammers.

> a flower seller signs up on Stack Overflow to get a backlink and puts the website link on their profile. Will this be helpful for SEO?

Profile links on SO are `rel="nofollow"`. The exception to this is if the users *rep* is [above a certain amount (2K+)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55843/299116) then the `nofollow` attribute appears to be removed.

If the profile backlink is a *follow* link then it might count for something, but it's not going to be much.